# svn: resync to changed path

Tags: svn, path

I needed to rename a path within my svn repository. How do I resync my local checkout with it?

Clarification:

Old path on the server was

```
http://myserver/vault/myrepos/systems/foo/branches/mybranch-0.1
```

New path on the server is now

```
http://myserver/vault/myrepos/systems/foo/branches/mybranch
```

Comment: Won't a simple `svn update` do?

Comment: No, because the repository's old path doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, it was just the `svn switch` (I was trying --relocate but I guess that's only needed if your whole repository moves to another server or another root URL).

```
svn switch http://myserver/vault/myrepos/systems/foo/branches/mybranch
```